# How to write jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, plugins, this

I would like to write a jQuery plugin, which is "bind" to a DIV element and it works with is. After couple of trial - error I ended up with just copying the example from this page - http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/.

So, I have an element

```
<div id="bends">test</div>
```

I have my basic definition taken from the example page:

```
(function ( $ ) {
    $.fn.greenify = function() {
        this.css( "color", "green" );
        console.log(this);
        return this;
   };
}( jQuery ));
```

and I call it like this

```
$("#bend").greenify();
```

Based on the example, I expect the text will become green. Unfortunatelly, nothing happens. When I console.log "this" object, it shows:

```
n.fn.init {context: document, selector: "#bend"}
```

So, I am affraid I am missing a basic point here. What is wrong - why "this" doesn't represent my element as it is in the example?

Comment: You have `<div id="**bends**">test</div>` but are querying for `$("#**bend**").greenify();`

Comment: thx, sry, I am working too long today ....

Answer (score -1, accepted):

please change the line to

```
$("#bends").greenify();
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$.fn.greenify = function() {
    this.css( "color", "green" );
    console.log(this);
    return this;
};

$('.color-me').greenify()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="color-me">Me</div>
```

Please see above, it works and console will log the jQuery object as it is.

Answer (score -1):

Calling `greenify` should return the element as a jQuery object. Tested in Google Chrome and the proper object was returned.

I was able to successfully run other jQuery functions on the object that was returned, as seen below:

`var x = $("#bend").greenify();
x.css('color', 'red');`

--

Also, in the question, you create an element with id `bend`, yet you refer to it in Javascript as `bends`. Rename one of these declarations to match the opposite.